# Having two non-parallel hyperplanes of $ \mathbb{R}^n $, $ S_1 $ and $ S_2 $, prove that $ S_1\cap S_2 \neq\emptyset $ and $\dim(S_1\cap S_2)=n-2$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I've got two affine hyperplanes of $ \mathbb{R}^n $, $ S_1 $ and $ S_2 $, which are **non**-parallels.

I have to prove that $ S_1\cap S_2 \neq\emptyset $ and $\dim(S_1\cap S_2)=n-2$

---

What I have done is:

As $ S_1 $ and $ S_2 $ are hyperplanes, $\dim(S_1)=n-1$ and $\dim(S_2)=n-1$

But I have no idea what else to do, I'm stuck :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does the non-parallel hypothesis mean ? Try to explore this fact to show the non emptyness of the intersection.

What can you say about the intersection of two linear hyperplanes ? Can you adapt this (maybe by translating the origin ?) to prove what is the dimension of the intersection ?

Comment: I know that if they are non-parallel, $\vec{S}_1\notin{\vec{S}_2}$ and $\vec{S}_2\notin{\vec{S}_1}$ and $\vec{S}_1\neq{\vec{S}_2}$ but anyway I don't know how to use it

Comment: You should have a formula like $dim(F + G) = dim F + dim G - dim (F \cap G)$, so you could find the dimension of the intersection.

Comment: Yes, but ehich is the dimension of the summ?

Comment: As they are different, there exists one vector in the first that is not in the second. This vector + the second hyperplane generates a vectors subspace of dimension 1 + (n-1) - (0) = n, so they generate together $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: I understand what you say; but what have I proved with that?

Comment: You proved that $H_1 + H_2 = \mathbb{R}^n$. Applying the previous dimension formula, you easily show that the intersection is of dimension $n-2$. Here $H_j$ stands for the direction of $S_j$.

Comment: Thanks! But what about the other part? I mean, I also have to prove that $ S_1\cap{S_2}\neq{\emptyset} $ . Or can I first calculate the dimension, and then say that as the dimension of the intersection is not zero,  $ S_1\cap{S_2}\neq{\emptyset} $ is true ?

Comment: Prove the first question before the second. For that, write $S_j = p_j + H_j$ for some point $p_j$ and show that if $H_1$ and $H_2$ are not equal (i.e S_1 and S_2 not parallel) then linear system $p_1 + v = p_2 + v_2$ have a solution for $v_ij\in H_j$ (using coordinates in $\mathbb{R^n}$ and basis of $H_j$). Then it is an affine non empty set. The second question gives its dimension.